# Dummy load on TV video input with RCA jack?

Tags: video, input

I have an old CRT-based HDTV that's pretty awesome for audio and I want to connect an audio source to one of its available audio/video inputs.  However, I don't have a video signal, just the left/right audio channels via RCA jacks.  This works okay, but when the TV is switched to that specific input, because there's no video signal present, it keeps a neon-green bit of text visible all the time that states the name of that specific input (e.g., "VIDEO 3").

Since it's a CRT and I don't want that text burning itself into the tube, is there a way to build a "dummy load" of some type to trick the TV into thinking there's a video signal attached so that it just shows a black screen?  I found [one document](http://www.mojo-audio.com/blog/breaking-in-cables-and-components/) (about midway down the page) that describes a design using a 75ohm resistor soldered to the two contacts in a standard RCA jack.  However, after building and trying it, the TV still displays "VIDEO 3".  Either I didn't solder it right, or I bought the wrong resistors.

Are there any other resources I can look up to get this to work?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. Maybe a candidate to migrate to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If that's the better location for this question, then please have it migrated.  There's so many SE sites now, it's hard to know what questions go where.  I figured, since I was dealing with audio/video cables, this would be the better site, as "dummy load" searches on Google reference a lot of audio-related results.

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem. One simple solution us to get an Arduino UNO, TVout library (comes with Arduino IDE) and compile and upload DemoNTSC example from that library. You will have to solder two resistors to the RCA video jack and that's about it. USB provides power. If you wish, you can program your own patterns or just make the screen black. Works nicely as a dummy composite video signal generator. See here https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/TVout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TV needs an actual video source to be detected. Simply terminating the input doesn't count. You need a video signal that has all the synchronization signals (which are detected) but the picture area is simply black. In video production this is called a "black generator".

This is typically an expensive piece of broadcast gear. But, because analog television is close to death, there is lots of old analog video gear available at very cheap prices. I went to  Ebay and found dozens of very inexpensive hits for: black burst generator.

Comment: Ah ha!  That is good information, thanks!  I grabbed a unit that looked to be in good condition, and I'll see if that addresses my issue.  If not, at least I have more information to continue research on.  I'll give you the points for this answer.  And for the Mods, if you guys know of a better Stack Exchange site suited for this question, please migrate this there.

Comment: The device I picked up works perfectly.  Thanks for this tip!